# Ionic 2 with MobileFirst 8

Tags: cordova, ionic2, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I am new to Ionic 2 with MobileFirst 8, Upto my knowledge i have installed Mobilefirst Server and MFP CLI Globally. I created Ionic project with android platfrom then i installed Cordova-plugin-mfp. When i tried to run ionic cordova emulate android throws

> Error: Failed to prepare plug-in for android : 
>   An unexpected error occurred. Contact IBM support.
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova emulate android (exit code 1).

Below are my System Details.

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.18.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.18.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.6
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
ios-deploy        : 1.9.2 
Node              : v6.11.0
npm               : 3.10.10 
OS                : macOS Sierra
Xcode             : Xcode 9.1 Build version 9B55
```

Before i Execute emulate command, executed **mfpdev app register** the app registered in my MobileFirst console then i moved with **mfpdev app webupdate** It throws other error

```
Error: Web resources could not be deployed for platform: android
Error: The mfpdev app webupdate command failed: ERRORDURINGEXTERNALSCRIPT
```

Can Anyone tell what is wrong in my environment and suggest some link for brief about Ionic 2 with Mobilefirst 8. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to test - can you open your project in Android Studio and try running against a device or emulator?

Comment: Please find the error log in Android Studio from the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m0f52wmqae2ccnm/Error.log.rtf?dl=0) @VivinK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the Cordova android platform versions supported by the MobileFirst plug-ins, is:
cordova-android: >= 6.1.2 and < 7.0

Try using command 'cordova platform add android@6.1.2'.

For more details see here :
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/sdk/cordova/

Comment: **Great answer** @Manju. After degrading my cordova android to 6.1.2 it started working. Awesome

Comment: @jais  my pleasure .Development of MobileFirst plugins  support for cordova-android version 7.0 (cordova 8 ) is under progress, support will be out soon.

Comment: @jais support for cordova-android version 7.0 (cordova 8 )  has been released see here :
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2018/04/09/8-0-ifix-release/